# work around the VirtualBox 4GB file size limit

Tags: virtualbox

I am stuck with the 4gb limit of the .vdi file. How can I get around this limit?

- HOST OS : Ubuntu 10.04
- Guest OS : Ubuntu 10.04
- filesystem: fat32 (where the vdi file is located)

Can I create another vdi file and mount it on file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have LVM in guest configured, then just create anothe vdi. Add to the machine. Then mount it and add to lvm as Physical Volume.

Next you can resize the Logical volume. And it works!

If you do not have LVm configured. Than you can add vdi and mount.But it will probably be just another part of filesystem. What you can do is to migrate your /home dir to this new volume, and then mount it as /home.

Comment: This question was open for such a long time.. Glad I got the right solution for my problem. The 4 gb limit was coming for ext4 format as well.

Comment: So... did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> filesystem: fat32 (where the vdi file is located)

That's where the 4GB file size limit comes from. Use ext3 (default for linux) or Reiser or any of the other modern filesystems.

Comment: I did move the file to ext4 partition, but same warning. Is there a way I can split the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a split disk image like so:

```
VBoxManage createhd --filename /path/to/my-disk.vmdk --size 8192 --format vmdk --variant split2g
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that there is a Virtualbox 4.0, you can resize VDI!

Answer (score 0):

I have virtualbox portable on my USB stick, with FAT32 filesystem. When I tried to use a dinamic VDI on a virtual machine with a size limit of 100Gb, Virtualbox display an advice telling to use NTFS filesystem instead of FAT, because FAT32 allows 4 Gb as maximum file size.